# Как делать синхронизацию базы копии сайта?

Tags: python, mysql, django, веб-программирование

Я хочу вопрос задать не просто про копию сайта на всякие пожарные. а именно резервную рабочую функциональную копию. Т.е. если основной не работает по каким либо причинам. на зеркале можно вполне успешно работать, заполнять, сохранять данные, распечатывать документы. А при поднятии основного, чтобы как то плавно все это дело синхронизировалось. и резервный сайт не нужен, например стал перенаправлять на основной. И самое главное чтобы база все изменения перенеслись.

Как такие системы реализуются. И как решается проблема синхронизации данных?

Сам сайт на джанго + mysql. Но это не новости или контент сайт. А црм. которая всегда нужна в работе особенно с утра до вечера. Было пара сбоев в течении года. по 1-3 часа сайт был не доступен и это все дело тормозило всю работу.

Comment: Отказоустойчивый кластер? если его сделать - то разумнее раскидать нагрузку, пусть работают все ноды, а при проблемах - только те, которые живы.